# Draw a recursive staircase function

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, recursion, lindenmayer

I am trying to draw the following figures shown below

[image]

However I am really unsure how to go about it. Sorry for not including a MWE as I usually do. But I do not know where I am going to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/staircase/.style={code={
  \draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) -| (0.5*#1,0.5*#1);
  \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
   {\draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1+\XX-1,-0.5*#1+\XX-1) |- ++ (1,1);
   \ifnum\XX<#1
   \draw[mydash,red] (-0.5*#1+\XX,-0.5*#1) -- ++ (0,\XX);
   \draw[mydash,blue] (0.5*#1,0.5*#1-\XX) -- ++ (-\XX,0);
   \fi}}},mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}]

 \path (0,-1.5) pic{staircase=1} (2,-1) pic{staircase=2}
 (5,-0.5) pic{staircase=3} (9,0) pic{staircase=4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This version has the origin at its "center" so is easier to rotate. However, in order to reproduce your figure you may be interested in a version that has the origin in the middle of the base line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/staircase/.style={code={
  \draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1,0) -| (0.5*#1,#1);
  \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
   {\draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1+\XX-1,\XX-1) |- ++ (1,1);
   \ifnum\XX<#1
   \draw[mydash,red] (-0.5*#1+\XX,0) -- ++ (0,\XX);
   \draw[mydash,blue] (0.5*#1,#1-\XX) -- ++ (-\XX,0);
   \fi}}},mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}]

 \path \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {({\X*(\X+1)/2-1},0) pic{staircase=\X} node[below=0.5ex] {$F_\X$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your uneven spacing problem: try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    pics/staircase/.style={code={
 \draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) -| (0.5*#1,0.5*#1);
 \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
  {\draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1+\XX-1,-0.5*#1+\XX-1) |- ++ (1,1);
  \ifnum\XX<#1
  \draw[mydash,red] (-0.5*#1+\XX,-0.5*#1) -- ++ (0,\XX);
  \draw[mydash,blue] (0.5*#1,0.5*#1-\XX) -- ++ (-\XX,0);
  \fi}}},mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}
}
\newcommand{\staircase}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \path (0,0) pic{staircase=#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
   {\begin{subfigure}[b]{\X.5cm}
       \centering
       \staircase{\X}
       \caption*{$F_\X$}
   \end{subfigure}}
   \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used your first version like so https://pastebin.com/b1zsCf7D . However this leads to some uneven spacing, do you know a fix for this as well? Btw, how do you answer these questions so fast! ;-)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Which spacing is uneven? Does it help if you replace the first draw command of the `pic` by `\draw[mydash] (-0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) --  (0.5*#1,-0.5*#1) -- (0.5*#1,0.5*#1);`? Or do you mean the gaps between the subfigures? This comes from the widths you give them by saying `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.09\textwidth}` and so on. (Slow marmots get caught by the eagels. Will be offline now for a bit.)