# Drawing colored sticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, lindenmayer

I am trying to draw some "matrices" that looks like this

[image]

So above the diagonal the sticks should be blue and below they should be red. Using some help from [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495488/8306) by [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495483/8306). I was able to produce the following result

[image]

using the code below. Any suggestions or improvements for the code? In particular I am not happy with hacking in

```
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,1) rectangle (#1-1,#1);
```

to obtain the correct bounding boxes.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}

\definecolor{stickBlue}{HTML}{0099ff}
\definecolor{stickRed}{HTML}{ff0033}

\tikzset{%
  pics/staircaseSum/.style={code={
      \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
      {\foreach \YY in {1,...,#1}
      {
      \ifnum\XX<\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickBlue] (\XX-1,\YY-1) -- (\XX-1, \YY);
      \fi
      \ifnum\XX>\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickRed] (\XX-1,\YY) -- (\XX-1, \YY+1);
       \fi
      }
      }
      }
    },
  mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}
}

\newcommand{\staircaseSum}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,1) rectangle (#1-1,#1); 
        \path (0,0) pic{staircaseSum=#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
   {\begin{subfigure}[b]{\X.5cm}
       \centering
       \staircaseSum{\X}
       \caption*{$F_\X$}
   \end{subfigure}}
   \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is very nice. The need for the bounding box can be waived by shifting the domain of `\YY` (or, alternatively, changing the code of the `pic`). The reason why you needed it in the first place was that you insert the coordinate `(0,0)` but because of the `\ifnum` the actual y values for the sticks started at `1`. (You can always find out what the current bounding box is by adding `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` at the end of the picture.)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}

\definecolor{stickBlue}{HTML}{0099ff}
\definecolor{stickRed}{HTML}{ff0033}

\tikzset{%
  pics/staircaseSum/.style={code={
      \foreach \XX [parse=true] in {0,...,#1-1}
      {\foreach \YY [parse=true] in {0,...,#1-1}
      {
      \ifnum\XX<\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickBlue] (\XX-1,\YY-1) -- (\XX-1, \YY);
      \fi
      \ifnum\XX>\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickRed] (\XX-1,\YY) -- (\XX-1, \YY+1);
       \fi
      }
      }
      }
    },
  mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}
}

\newcommand{\staircaseSum}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0) pic{staircaseSum=#1};
        %\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
   {\begin{subfigure}[b]{\X.5cm}
       \centering
       \staircaseSum{\X}
       \caption*{$F_\X$}
   \end{subfigure}}
   \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative definition of the `pic` is

```
\tikzset{%
  pics/staircaseSum/.style={code={
      \foreach \XX [parse=true] in {1,...,#1}
      {\foreach \YY [parse=true] in {1,...,#1}
      {
      \ifnum\XX<\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickBlue] (\XX-1,\YY-2) -- (\XX-1,\YY-1);
      \fi
      \ifnum\XX>\YY
        \draw[ultra thick,shorten <=1.5mm,stickRed] (\XX-1,\YY-1) -- (\XX-1, \YY);
       \fi
      }
      }
      }
    },
  mydash/.style={thick,shorten <=1mm,dash pattern=on 8mm off 2mm}
}
```

Comment: Oooh, nice idea. Any idea why using `[parse=true]` is giving me the error `Package pgfkeys Error: 
 do not know the key '/pgf/foreach/parse' to which you passed 'true'`?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Probably you have not the newest pgf version installed. So you need to either install it or use the alternative definition at the bottom of the answer.